# DB2 select to set parameters and then insert with param values

Tags: php, sql, db2

I'm trying to use PDO to prepare a DB2 insert in a php script and it's giving me the error 'Parameter Marker or NULL not valid'

I'm running a select query to get values and set them as parameters, then I have my insert statement set. I prepare it and, within a while loop based on fetch from first query, I set the params so that I'll be able to run the insert with the values I need. The problem is it's failing at the line where I prepare the insert.

The first query runs and prints

```
[ORDERNUMBER] 123456
[CUSTOMER] 1
[PRODUCT] 123
[FABR] A
[COLOR] 1
[SHIPDATE] 20181119
```

So the data comes back and I've even started to cast my data types but I still get the error.

Here's the initial select that prints the above:

```
//SELECT query to get source data
$getOrderDetails = "
    SELECT 
         cast(invnoc as int) as ORDERNUMBER,
         cast(cstnoc as int) AS CUSTOMER,
         cast(PRODUCTc as int) AS PRODUCT,
         cast(covr1c as int) AS FABR,
         cast(colr1c as int) AS COLOR ,
         cast(extd2d as varchar(45)) AS SHIPDATE,
    FROM testTable g
";

try {
    $orderDetailCheck = $DB2conn->prepare($getOrderDetails);
    $detailRslt = $orderDetailCheck->execute();
    $orderDetailCount = $orderDetailCheck->fetch();
    print_r($orderDetailCount);
}catch(PDOException $ex) {
    echo "QUERY ONE FAILED!: " .$ex->getMessage();
}
```

Insert statement:

```
$insertPlacement = "
    INSERT INTO table (CUSTOMER_id, start_date, expire_date)
    SELECT DISTINCT
        :CUSTOMER, 
        (to_date(:SHIPDATE, 'YYYYMMDD') + 7 DAYS)  as start_date,
        (to_date(:SHIPDATE, 'YYYYMMDD') + 127 DAYS)  as expire_date
    from OFSTable ofs
    WHERE  ofs.PRODUCT=:PRODUCT AND ofs.FABR1=:FABR AND ofs.color1=:COLOR;
";
```

Setting the params:

```
//this line is failing
$insert = $DB2conn->prepare($insertPlacement);

while ($row2 = $orderDetailCheck->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {

    $insertParams = [
        ":CUSTOMER" => $row2["CUSTOMER"],
        ":ORDERNUMBER" => $row2["ORDERNUMBER"],
        ":PRODUCT" => $row2["PRODUCT"],
        ":FABR" => $row2["FABR"],
        ":COLOR" => $row2["COLOR"],
    ];
```

I realize that the problem is I can't call parameters as column names or table names but this worked in mysql and it's not for db2. I need to insert the value for the :CUSTOMER parameter but it's acting like I can't to that. How should I alter this to work on db2 as it was on Mysql?

Comment: Did you tryied to cast all parameters?  `SELECT DISTINCT CAST(:CUSTOMER AS INT)  ... fs.PRODUCT=CAST(:PRODUCT AS INT) ...`

Comment: I believe you are correct. Let me try one more thing, but I think that solved it

Comment: Perfect, that got it! thanks so much, if you answer I'll accept

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should to cast all parameters. Like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT CAST(:CUSTOMER AS INT) ... fs.PRODUCT=CAST(:PRODUCT AS INT) ...
```

Source:

[SQL Call builder returns 'A statement contains a use of a parameter marker that is not valid.. SQLCODE=-418, SQLSTATE=42610'](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21380540)